# A different google_sign_in Exception with : ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

I am getting the following error when I was trying to Google sign in from my flutter App.

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , *null, null)

One different thing I have found in this Exception as compared to all other questions available in Stack Overflow is, here are 2 null -

> ApiException: 10: , null, null)

- I have added both the SHA into the firebase
- I have tried flutter clean
- I have tried to change the firebase project
- I have also tried to rebuild the app from scratch and also with the new firebase project.

Following is the `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.5 at D:\app_development\flutter
    • Framework revision adc687823a (7 days ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
    • Engine revision b09f014e96
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\aryan pegwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.72
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.42

• No issues found!

following is the flutter run  :-

Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        13.1s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
D/EGL_emulation( 7571): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb766c80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdeccb3d0)
D/eglCodecCommon( 7571): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...                85ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:52578/PXVd2TjxZhA=/

Flutter DevTools, a Flutter debugger and profiler, on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A52578%2FPXVd2TjxZhA%3D%2F

 Running with sound null safety 
W/ActivityThread( 7571): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ccd6b14
D/EGL_emulation( 7571): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb7658a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdb7a7320)
D/EGL_emulation( 7571): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdb7658a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdb7a7320)
E/flutter ( 7571): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter ( 7571): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:581:7)
E/flutter ( 7571): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter ( 7571): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7571): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)
E/flutter ( 7571): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7571):
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, I forgot to set the 'support email' in the Firebase settings

Answer (score 1):

Debug case:-
SHA key is a major role here.
if we generate a build from your machine, make sure the provided SHA key belongs to that device only, What I mean is, Generate an SHA key in your machine and provide that SHA key

```
keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head against this for hours, for an app that had previously worked fine.

All SHA-1 keys I could find (debug, release, Play Signing) were added to Firebase.

After "trying everything" I decided to thoroughly check them in [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) as well. It turns out that they were all there already.

**BUT - one of them had been added to the wrong project! After deleting it from that project and adding it to the correct one, Google Sign In started working immediately again.**

Why this suddenly became an issue after years of having the SHA-1 key in the wrong project and a seemingly working app on the Play Store is beyond me. But this might help others struggling with sudden `ApiException: 10: , null, null`.